# Aligning Content in an Android ListView

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

I apologize for this question may have been asked somewhere, but I'm not sure how to phrase it.

I have a ListView in my Android app and I want to align the content in each row so that each TextView is aligned with corresponding TextViews in rows below it (left, right, and center).

This picture is what I'm going for listview:

[image]

So, the left TextView is aligned all the way to the left and the right TextView is aligned all the way to the right. The center TextView is aligned such that it always "begins" at the same place (ie. it's position is not affected by the length of the left TextView).

How can I achieve this? Thanks a lot

Comment: I think you have use horizontal layout..right

Comment: Use a tablelayout :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use bellow like.. I have used first textview left, second center & third is right. You can change as your wish...

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_textview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="AAP 500" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_textview2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="85.65" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_textview3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="-3.75(-3.34 %)" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use a LinearLayout with horizontal orientation then apply a weight to each of the textviews inside of it. this will cause them to each take a certain fraction of the layout. You can start by giving them each a weight of 1 and adjusting from there. The right-most textview will also need a right justification on the text to match the picture.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create custom listView in that your item_row_view.xml will look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="AAP 500"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_textview2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="85.65"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_textview3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="-3.75(-3.34 %)"
        android:textAlignment="center" />


</RelativeLayout>
```